# TypeError: Cannot call method of undefined

Tags: node.js

Trying to build a restapi using nodejs I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCategories' of undefined
```

My project structure is like this

models

-- dbhandler.js

node_modules

package.json

app.js

dbconnection.js

My dbhandler code is here

```
var db = require('../dbconnection');
var getData = {
getCategories : function() {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM categories"
    db.connection.connect();
    db.connection.query(sql,function(error, results, fields){
        if (!error){
            console.log('The solution is: ', results);
            console.log('The solution fields is: ', fields);
        } else{
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        }
    });
}};
module.exports = getData;
```

And my app.js code is here :

```
var dbhandler = require('./models/dbhandler')
var router = express.Router(); 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
dbhandler.getData.getCategories();
res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});
```

Comment: and where do you call your `getData`??? What is actually the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post
error 'TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCategories' of undefined'
by calling dbhandler.getData.getCategories();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be dbhandler.getCategories() as you are importing dbhandler as an object through this `var dbhandler = require('./models/dbhandler')`

Comment: But I'm exporting here getData for getcategories objects.

Comment: What you've done is not exporting ```getData```. Instead, you are assigning the ```getData``` variable which is an object to ```module.exports```. So when you require it, it should be an object. ```getCategories``` in this case is the key of the object you've exported.